# Vocabulary: numeral system where "||" represents "2"

Tags: number-systems

A useful system in some contexts where are you counting things is writing

> 1 as |
>
> 2 as ||
>
> 3 as |||
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 11 as <s>||||</s> <s>||||</s> |

Example of usefulness is keeping track of the number of cars that pass over a bridge.

**What is the system called?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This system is called [*tally marks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks).